# How to provide initial windows username during installation with Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

So I've just installed new Windows on new laptop and used my Microsoft account during installation. Now my user directory name is several characters of my first name starting from uppercase character and I DONT LIKE IT. Generally it's better to recreate the user with desired name, but since it's initial user I can't do that.

Is it possible to pass such parameters to the installer somehow?

Comment: Simple: Disassociate your MS account and by doing so create a NEW local account, once logged into the new Local Account, associate that account with your MS account.  **This is the only way to do what you want**

Comment: @Ramhound why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: Because already have to a previous question